# sinon stub a firebase collection with chained methods for unit testing...(sinon, node/express, Jasmine)

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, unit-testing, sinon

In my nodejs code, I have a snippet:

```
   await cfDB.collection('users').doc(userAccount.uid).set({
      email: 'email@domain.com',
      firstName: 'firstname',
      lastName: 'Lastname,
    });
```

How would I create a sinon mock of this for unit test with jasmine?

more complete context....

```
 const { Firestore } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

  const cfDB = new Firestore();

  // Create Firestore user document
  try {
    await cfDB.collection('users').doc('E7skP0IncSW7wkBxnrYFx6udzGH2').set({
      email: 'email@domain.com',
      firstName: 'Firstname',
      lastName: 'Lastname',
    });


  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ success: false, payload: { message: 'Firebase User write error. ' + error } });
    return;
  }

  // Success
  res.json({ success: true, payload: { message: 'User created.', userAccount: userAccount } });
}
```

Comment: What's `cfDB`? Show complete, minimal code

Comment: I added more context.

Comment: Where does `res` come from?

Comment: res is the http response

Comment: Can you show a minimal, complete code

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution...

```
        const collectionStub = sinon.stub(firebase.cfDB, 'collection')
        .get(() => {
            return function() {
                return {
                    doc: (path) => {
                        return {
                            set: () => [{user: 'mock-user-1'}, {user: 'mock-user-2'}]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer, in order to help others who read this question in future. Also, thanks for the help

Comment: what is that line `set: () => [{user: 'mock-user-1'}, {user: 'mock-user-2'}]` doing? Is it checking the parameters called to `set()`?  How could you test the value of `path`? Just an assert?  How would you test a read request and mock it returning values that you want? If you will update your answer with more info  / examples, I will happily award you bonus points.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for Google Functions there is a
number of great examples of using sinon to stub Firebase Realtime Database and Firestore. Its the ones listed as offline examples.

I believe they should be able to work in any Node.js context. Also express.

You can find them here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing

Comment: This answer was particularly useful to me because it includes an explanations and recommendations on Google's part for when to opt for real-time vs stubbed interactions in testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on it, but I've been able to get this far for now:

```
function stubTest(path: string, result: any){
    sinon.stub(admin, 'firestore')
    .get(() => {
        return function() {
            return stubCollection(path, result);            
        }
    });
}
function stubDoc(path: string, result: any){
    const parts = path.split('/');
    const rest = parts.slice(1).join('/');
    return {
        doc: () => {
            if(rest){
                return stubCollection(rest, result);
            }else {
                return {
                    get: () => stubData(result)               
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
function stubCollection(path: string, result: any){
    const parts = path.split('/');
    const rest = parts.slice(1).join('/');
    return {
        collection: () => {
            if(rest){
                return stubDoc(rest, result);
            }else {
                return {
                    get: () => stubData(result)
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
function stubData(result: any){
    return {
        data: () => result
    }
}
```

and to use it you only need to call `stubTest("restaurants/12333/orders/123111", {mockResponse: "someData"});`

this will mock a call like this one

```
const order = (await firestore.collection('restaurants').doc('12333').collection('orders').doc('123111').get()).data();
```

Ofc there is a long way to go, adding more mock methods but at least I dont need to write stubs multiple times

Comment: Do you have any more complete code to post? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example on how I use sinon to mock away Firestore.

In the function-under-test `getAssets` I pass `firestore` as its first argument. You can also choose just replace a global `firestore` variable using `rewire` or `proxyquire` or any other way, that would be out of scope for this answer.

In the test, there is an example `AssetData[]` that represents a collection. And the call to `setupAssets` turns this into a mocked `firestore` that would return this collection when queried.

The function `setupAssets` returns all the intermediate mocks it creates as well, these can be inspected for their call arguments and number of calls in your test.

Example test with mocked firestore:

```js
it('gets existing assets', async () => {
  const userId = 'user-id'
  const assetName = 'asset-name'
  const assets: AssetData[] = [{ asset: assetName, amount: 1, avgPrice: '1.00' }]
  const { firestore } = setupAssets(assetName, userId, assets)

  const result = await assetFuncs.getAssets(firestore, userId, assetName)
  t.deepEqual(result.docs, assets)
})
```

The actual code that gets the assets:

```js
async function getAssets (firestore: firestore.Firestore, userId: string, asset: string) {
  const colRef = firestore.collection(`users/${userId}/assets`)
  const query = colRef.where('asset', '==', asset)
  return query.get()
}
```

And finally the sinon mocking function that sets up a fake Firestore:

```js
function setupAssets (assetName: string, userId: string, assets: AssetData[]) {
  const firestore = sinon.createStubInstance(firestore.Firestore)
  const collectionRef = sinon.createStubInstance(firestore.CollectionReference)
  const query = sinon.createStubInstance(firestore.Query)
  const querySnapshot = sinon.createStubInstance(firestore.QuerySnapshot)
  const docSnapshots = assets.map(asset => {
    const docSnapshot = sinon.createStubInstance(firestore.DocumentSnapshot)
    Object.defineProperty(docSnapshot, 'id', { value: crypto.randomUUID() })
    docSnapshot.data.returns(asset)
    return docSnapshot
  })
  Object.defineProperty(querySnapshot, 'docs', { value: docSnapshots })
  query.get.resolves(querySnapshot)
  collectionRef.where.withArgs('asset', '==', assetName).returns(query)
  firestore.collection.withArgs(`users/${userId}/assets`).returns(collectionRef)
  return { firestore, collectionRef, query, querySnapshot, docSnapshots }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You wouldn't use `sinon` to mock this, you would make use of the [`@firebase/rules-unit-testing`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/rules-unit-testing) package to force interaction with a Firestore/RTDB emulator.

Comment: I thought the firebase rules-unit-testing was just for testing security rules???

Comment: @SteveGeggie While that is the primary purpose, in order to test the security rules, it needs to be able to interact with Firestore and the RTDB, which it does using the emulators. You can make use of those same Firestore and RTDB methods here, just skip on the testing security rules part.

Comment: Are you certain this is impossible to mock using sinon?   that is our team standard.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, but I'm not seeing the reason why you would unit test against a mocked database rather than the emulator that properly mimics the real thing and is designed for testing against.

Comment: @samthecodingman From my perspective it is two distinctly different things. When I need to test behaviour depending on the database I will use firebase testing library to mimic the database. Sometimes however I need to test some other thing, which for some reason is located in a class or function that also uses the firebase SD. Then I think it is nice to just be able to provide a simple stub.